# How to use aggregate functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, conditional-statements, aggregate-functions

I have a situation where I have a Customer table and I need to locate document numbers from a column which is structured as a string where the first 4 characters represent the type of document (e.g.,'BILL000000000001', 'PYMT000000000001'). Each of these documents also has a corresponding document date. I want to fetch the **CustomerNumber** where the **DocType** is *BILL* with the **max(DocDate)** and return the **CustomerNumber** and the **DocDate**. This part is fairly straightforward and presents no challenge.

My problem is that some customers do not as yet have a document starting with 'BILL'. For those, I want to fetch the **CustomerNumber** and **max(DocDate)** that matches another string *XXXX* as the first 4 characters. In essence, I need to use some sort of conditional expression that fetches either the **CustomerNumber** and **max(DocDate)** for a BILL type, or the **Customer Number** and **max(DocDate)** for a *XXXX* type of record. The issue is that there is a possibility that both a *BILL* and *XXXX* type might exist for a Customer. Where a *BILL* exists, I want to pick the **CustomerNumber** and **max(DocDate)** for that customer. However, where an *XXXX* type exists but no *BILL* type document is available, I need the **CustomerNumber** and **max(DocDate)** for type *XXXX*.

I was thinking of using **EXCEPT** and **UNION** but I don't think either option really works for me. Here's my SQL with **EXCEPT**, if it helps at all.

```
select CustomerNumber, max(DocDate)
FROM Table1
where substring(DocumentNumber,1,4) = 'BILL'
group by CustomerNumber
EXCEPT
select CustomerNumber, max(DocDate)
from Table1
where substring(umDocumentNumber,1,4) = 'MISC'
group by CustomerNumber
```

Comment: `select CustomerNumber, max(DocDate)
FROM Table1
where substring(DocumentNumber,1,4) IN ( 'BILL','MISC') GROUP BY CustomerNumber` ?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be worth paragraphs of explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your logic, you need the `CustomerNumber` and `MAX(DocDate)` for customers that have a `BILL` type record, and you also need the `CustomerNumber` and `MAX(DocDate)` for any customers where a `BILL` type record does not exist.

A `UNION` of your initial results and another result set that includes a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause should return what you're looking for.

```
SELECT 
   CustomerNumber
    ,max(DocDate)
FROM Table1
WHERE substring(DocumentNumber, 1, 4) = 'BILL'
GROUP BY CustomerNumber

UNION ALL

SELECT 
   CustomerNumber
    ,max(DocDate)
FROM Table1 AS out
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Table1 AS in
              WHERE 
                in.CustomerNumber = out.CustomerNumber
                AND
                substring(umDocumentNumber, 1, 4) = 'BILL'
GROUP BY CustomerNumber;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want using aggregation:

```
select CustomerNumber,
       coalesce(max(case when DocumentNumber like 'BILL%' then DocDate end),
                max(DocumentNumber)
               )
from Table1
where DocumentNumber like 'BILL%' or DocumentNumber like 'MISC%'
group by CustomerNumber;
```

Or using window functions:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by CustomerNumber
                                order by left(DocumentNumber, 4), DocDate desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from Table1 t1
     ) t1
where seqnum = 1;
```

This method allows you to return the entire row for the maximum document.